# True or False: $A\cap (B\times C)=(A\cap B)\times (A\cap C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

True or false. Prove by showing the statement is true in general or by giving a counter example.
$A\cap (B\times C)=(A\cap B)\times (A\cap C)$

I'm not sure what the question is trying to get at. Maybe there is some way to write the left to look like the right?

Comment: Let $B=C$, for concreteness both equal to $\{k\}$. Let $A=B\times C$. Then the left side is $B\times C$, non-empty, while the right side is the empty set.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, similarly, if $A=B=C\not=\emptyset$, then the left hand side is empty, while the right hand side is $A\times A$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: Yes, weird question, the objects $B\times C$ and $A$ are of different "types."

Comment: @BarryCipra Just to nitpick: Not necessarily.  Let $a \in A$ and $(a,a) \in A$.  Then $A \cap A \times A$ is not empty.  However unless $A = A \times A$  then $A \cap A \times A \ne A \times A$.  $A = A \times A$ is possible but it is far from the norm.

Comment: It is possible (I think) to come up with a case where this is true but that is for from the norm.  BxC is a set of ordered pairs.  A need not have any order pairs.  If A, B and C are subsets of R or any other "one dimensional" spaces then LHS is empty.

Comment: @fleablood, hardly a nitpick! You are quite right, I vastly overstated the case.  I should have said "if $A=B=C=\{\emptyset\}$...."

Comment: I wouldn't say "vastly".  $A \cap B x C$ is an intersection of a "single dimension" set and "cross product" and aren't the same "type" at all.  Actually, I stated it's possible for A = A x A which .... is it?

Comment: @fleablood, OK then, "grossly" instead of "vastly."

Answer (score 3):

Take $A=\{0, 1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{0,1\}$. Therefore, $A\cap (B\times C)=\{0,1\}\cap\{(1,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,1)\}=\emptyset$, but $(A\cap B)\times (A\cap C)=\{1\}\times\{0,1\}=\{(1,0), (1,1)\}$, and therefore, this isn't true.

Comment: Wouldn't (A∩B)×(A∩C) ={(1,0),(1,1)} ?

Comment: yes, sorry, just fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

The statement doesn't really make much sense if you think about it.  B x C is a set of ordered pairs.  So if $A \cap (B \times C)$ isn't empty A must have some points that are ordered pairs.  The right hand side, however, allows A,B, and C to be "simple" sets that need not have any ordered pairs.  These are ... very different concepts.

Consider $A = B = C = \mathbb R$.

Then $A \cap (B \times C) = \mathbb R \cap (\mathbb R \times \mathbb R) = \emptyset$.

But $(A \cap B) \times (A \cap C) = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for that direction of thought.